# AJAX запросы PUT и DELETE в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как послать асинхронный запрос на Update/Delete, применяя обычную библиотеку Java Script? В инете вижу jQuery и т.п, но при моём задании мне нужно решение на чистом JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
var r = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
 //PUT GET DELETE POST
 r.open("POST", "webservice", true);
 r.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return; 
   console.log(r.responseText);
 };
 r.send("a=1&b=2&c=3");
```

Comment: Я спрашивал насчёт "Put" and "Delete"..

Comment: Попробуй вместо "POST" PUT , но там доп. конфиги нужны, да и PUT блокируется в первоначальных настройках апача( если к пхп коннект )

Comment: @Maks.Burkov добавил комментарий

Comment: Что за конфиги нужны ? конект к Java..